# Программа на C++ работает правильно, а на Pascal нет

Tags: c++, c, pascal, freepascal

**pascal:**

```
//fpc 3.0.0    

program HelloWorld;

var x:double;

function fact(n:integer):integer;
begin
  if(n = 0) then fact := 1
  else fact := n*fact(n-1);
end;

function pows(x:double;y:integer):double;
begin
  if(y = 0) then pows := 1
  else pows := x*pows(x,y-1);
end;

function func(x:double):double;
var n:integer;
begin
   n:= 8;
   func := pows(-1,n)*pows(x,2*n+1)/(fact(n)*(2*n+1));
end;

begin
    x := func(2);
    write(x);
end.
```

**Результат:** x = -0.30576

**C++**

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact (int i){
    return (!i)?1:i*fact(i-1);
}

double pows(double x,int y){
    return (!y)?1:x*pows(x,y-1);
}

double func(double x){
    int n = 8;
    return pows(-1,n)*pows(x,2*n+1)/(fact(n)*(2*n+1));
}

int main()
{
    double x = func(2);
    cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

**Результат:** x = 0.191223;

Я конечно понимаю что побочные функции есть в модулях `cmath` и `math` но не суть важно, ответ совпадает до `n = 7` а дальше сами видите. В общем ошибка помоему тривиальна, но если поможете её найти, буду благодарен.

Comment: А какой ответ верный, если посчитать руками или на калькуляторе? Я верю, что эти примеры можно сильно уменьшить - примерно до нескольких арифметических действий. Или захардкодить результаты вычисления некоторых функций. Сделайте, пожалуйста - это поможет выделить проблему.

Comment: на самом деле я бы проверял переполнения. В паскале ставлю на ошибку. 8!*17 ~ 680k > 65k - не влезает в integer. Дальше может быть ЧТО УГОДНО. Попробуйте на LongInt заменить в паскале ради интереса.

Comment: и ещё, за pow(-1,n) я бы очень сильно ругался... И за рекурсию, где обычного цикла хватит.

Comment: Эхх вообщем то да, проблема была в int'aх поставил везде double чтоб уж точно хватило и заработало, ну спасибо и на том что откликнулись )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что в С++ `int` *обычно* не меньше 32 бит (вряд ли вы 16 бит найдёте), а в Паскале `integer` именно 16 бит. Вместо него следует использовать `LongInt` или `int64`/`QWord`

Из-за возникновения переполнения результаты отличаются.

UPD. В паскале это зависит от настроек компилятора, битности компилятора и системы. В С++ примерно так же. 16 бит для паскаля - значение по умолчанию. В С++ обычно на 32 бита можно рассчитывать. Чтобы избегать подобного советую **всегда** использовать типы с точным размером.

Comment: Просто привык что на С++ для int  4 байта заглаза вот и "приуныл" ))

Comment: @vadosinferno именно поэтому я всегда Long приписывал на паскале. кстати обратите внимание на Word (LongWord QWord) они тут лучше подходят.

Comment: да легко 16бит int найти - просто взять 16 битный компилятор. А вот integer  в паскале 32битном (fpc или делфи) - должне быть 4 байта. А в турбопаскале как раз и будет 16 бит

Comment: @KoVadim ну 16 бит С++ компилятор я один раз видел) это BC был (и то С++ с натяжкой). А вот в паскале - нет. fpc даже 64 бита может быть, но `integer` там всё равно 16. http://ideone.com/kB61JX вот это fpc. Глючки какие-то На олимпиаде горело у многих от этого. Вроде бы это в настройках компилятора задаётся, но кто туда лазит...

Comment: просто нужно знать, что у fpc есть режимы. 32битный integer будет только в режимах delphi и objfpc. https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progap4.html#progse75.html А то, глюки глюки... доки нужно читать

Comment: @KoVadim для олимпиадника - глюки) настройки ему никто править не даст. После этого я твёрдо решил никогда не юзать непостоянные по размеру типы данных...

Comment: @pavel, тогда вам не повезло. Не поучаствуете во многих проектах ;)